# Push new items into JSON array

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

Let's say this is the table inside my collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("557cf6bbd8efe38c627bffdf"),
    "name" : "John Doe",
    "rating" : 9,
    "newF" : [
        "milk",
        "Eggs",
        "Beans",
        "Cream"
    ]
}
```

Once a user types in some input, it is sent to my node server, and my node server then adds that item to the list `"newF"`, which is then sent back to my `MongoDB` and saved.
I'm trying to use update, which can successfully change the values inside of this table, but I'm not sure how to add new items onto that list. I did it with `$push` inside the `MongoDB shell`, but not sure how to do it on node.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
db.collection('connlist').update({ _id: new ObjectId("e57cf6bb28efe38c6a7bf6df")}, { name: "JohnDoe", rating: 9, newF: ["Milk, Eggs", "Beans"] }, function(err,doc){
      console.log(doc);
    });
```

Comment: You can have a look at Mongoose http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html

Comment: I'm not using Mongoose.

Comment: That was the point, you should be using a library

Comment: Any way of doing it without using mongoose? or is it impossible otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the syntax for adding new items is just the same as in the shell:

```js
// make sure you actually imported "ObjectID"
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

db.collection('conlist').update(
    { "_id": new ObjectId("e57cf6bb28efe38c6a7bf6df") },
    { "$push": { "newF": { "$each": [ "cream", "butter" ] } } },
    function(err,numAffected) {
        // do something in the callback
    }
)
```

Or perhaps use [**`.findOneAndUpdate()`**](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) if you want to return the modified document instead of just making the alteration.

Of course use [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) and possibly with [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) which allows multiple array elements to be added when adding to an array. If you want "unique" items then use [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) where your operation allows.

And generally speaking for other items you should use [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) or other operators in the update portion of your document. Without these operators you are just "replacing" the document content with whatever structure you place in the "update" portion of your statement.